# Put text at bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I have 4 DIV's right next to each other, and they're all centered in the middle of the screen. I have 2 words in each div, but I don't want them at the top, I want them to appear in the bottom right hand corner of the div. How can I do this?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Wrap the text in a `span` or similar and use the following CSS:

```css
.your-div {
    position: relative;
}

.your-div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also use css properties like: `vertical-align:bottom;` and `float:right;`. Can't you?

Comment: @Harry `vertical-align` only works if the element has `display: table-cell` which isn't supported in < IE8.

Comment: this works great... if you don't care much about your heights.

Comment: Does not work on JS libs inncluding ReactJS and Next JS. Any workaround?

Comment: Its the div position i was missing!  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
<div id="container">
    <div><span>Two Words</span></div>
    <div><span>Two Words</span></div>
    <div><span>Two Words</span></div>
    <div><span>Two Words</span></div>
</div>

#container{
    width:450px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#container div{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#container div span{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7YTYu/2/

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @Harry the following code works for me:

```
.your-div{
   vertical-align: bottom;
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: This worked but Text align isn't working the text is just aligned to left side and i can't change it

Answer (score 7):

If you only have one line of text and your div has a fixed height, you can do this:

```
div {
    line-height: (2*height - font-size);
    text-align: right;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k752q/).

Answer (score 4):

I think that's better to use flex boxes ([compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)) than the absolute position. Here's example from me in pure css.

```css
.container{
  background-color:green;
  height:500px;
  
  /*FLEX BOX */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.elem1{
  background-color:red;
  padding:20px;
  
   /*FLEX BOX CHILD */
 -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 TOP OF CONTAINER 
<div class="elem1">
  Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Sed a libero. Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci.

Mauris sollicitudin fermentum libero. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Quisque id mi.

Donec venenatis vulputate lorem. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat feugiat, eros pede varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: When bottom is in question, I think `flex-direction: column` can usualy help out better

Comment: It's because of  vendor-prefixed properties. Without that it's not that much :)

Comment: Don't you think we have lost the battle when you have to add code like this just to put stuff on the bottom of a div?

Comment: I think you don't need vendor prefixes anymore. StackOverflow lacks the feature of knowing in what version of browser it was tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `display: table` to the parent element and `display: table-cell` for the child element.

I.e.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  width: 115px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .child {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Content goes in here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```