# Align text to the bottom of a big <a> element

Tags: html, css

How can I align text to the bottom right of a big `<a>` element inside a div?

Here is what I have, but I want the text at the bottom of the box. I've searched a lot and nothing has worked for me:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <a href="http://link.com">Link to somewhere</a>
</div>​
```

with the following css:

```
.thumbnail{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;}

.thumbnail a{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightgrey;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8JsPV/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your HTML and put the entire thing in an `<a>` tag so it is all clickable. [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8JsPV/2/).

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><div class="thumbnail"><span>Link to somewhere</span></div>​</a>​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
 .thumbnail{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.thumbnail span{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}​
```

EDIT:

To do it WITHOUT putting an div inside the `<a>`, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8JsPV/4/).

Comment: Thanks but the problem with that is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: That does work! but it still is not a very elegant solution. I would think there must be a way to truly align it to the bottom...

Comment: I don't think you can without some sort of position tag. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288336/put-text-at-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 2):

This should help if you change the HTML accordingly:

```
.thumbnail{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://link.com"><div class="thumbnail">Link to somewhere</div></a>​
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JsPV/3/)

Comment: The problem with this is that the `<a>` does not fill the area anymore (I think OP wanted the whole thing to be clickable).

Comment: The problem with that is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.thumbnail
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: Orange;
        display: block;

    }

    .thumbnail span
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        background-color: Gray;
    }
```

and change the HTML like so

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img
   src="http://www.healthfiend.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Facial-Exercises.jpg"
   alt="face" /><span>Link to somewhere</span></a>
```

This makes the whole thing clickable and aligns the text to the bottom right. I replaced you div with an img tag as I assume for a thumbnail this is actually what you probably want in the end. Right?

Comment: Thanks but I need the whole div to be "clickable"