# How can I align 2 divs inside another div to the bottom and to the left/right

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I have this code

> HTML

```
  <div class="head">
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
    </div>
  </div>
```

> CSS

```
.head {
    height:110px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
.search {
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is put the `div "menu"` at the bottom left of the `div "head"` and the `div "search"` at the bottom right of the `div "head"`.

When I use the position and bottom values for `"menu"` and `"head"` it aligns the menu perfectly, but when I try the same thing with `"search"` it throws it on top of `"menu"` offset a little.

Here is a picture example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBUxw.png
(the "menu" div aligns correctly but "search" aligns to the left and on top of the "menu" a little higher)

Getting rid of position and bottom values and using just float will align each to their respective sides inline with each other, but it won't put them on the bottom of the parent div.

I've got as far as getting them to align to the sides, but the "search" div is still higher than "menu" (and not on the bottom).

This might be because it has a form in it with a input search field.

> Edit1

: I've found out that the problem is that I need to actually align the search box to the bottom of "search". I tried adding this to .searchbox

```
.searchbox {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

But this does not work, and neither does bottom:0px;.

> Edit2

: I found the solution since I found out what the problem actually was. I had to add this code to a class assigned to the input box

```
position: absolute;
right:    0;
bottom:   0;
```

And now it's working perfect. I don't have any other content inside "search" except the box so aligning the div "search" isn't too big of a deal since now the input box is aligning to "head". Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing this and it seemed to work for me in Chrome and Firefox. Also, your second to last closing div needs to be fixed.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jhhboyle/pen/BZQVvO

Link to another thread that was helpful with the bottom / right / left styling: 
[Put text at bottom of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288336/put-text-at-bottom-of-div)

HTML:

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="menu">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      COntent
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.head {
    height:110px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}
.menu {
    font-size:18px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
.search {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I'll fix the tag but this is just a sample I wrote for here. I got rid of the floats in CSS but search still won't move to the bottom. I think it might be because it has a form in it with search box. I'll add details to original post.

Comment: This worked but I had a problem with the search box. I included details in the first post. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

[A div with two div's align left and right bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpgrD.png)

Try this in CSS file:

```
.head {
    height:110px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
.search {
right:0px;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an another div with `position:absolute;` and put both child div inside it.

css

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top:1px solid;
}
    .menu {
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.search {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="menu">
          hello
    </div>
    <div class="search">
          bye
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
.head {
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top:1px solid;
}

.menu {
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.search {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="menu">
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      bye
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a another way to get the same

**[2nd way to do this](https://jsfiddle.net/b6L3d766/2/)**

**[3rd way to do this](https://jsfiddle.net/b6L3d766/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this seems messy, adding another div. Is this a practical way of doing it or sloppy?

Comment: This a practical way because the both div which you want to bottom so i created a parent div for both.

Comment: I make a fiddle with another solution if you don't want to do previous one check update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` to align the divs to the bottom left and right.

```css
.head {
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu, .search {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="menu">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    Search
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works, but my "search" div is offset from the bottom by about 10 pixels. The "search" has a form in it with a input box. There is no button or breaks in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.menu{left:0;}

.search{right:0;}
```

Comment: That moved the "search" div to the right, but it is still not aligned to the bottom.