# How to align content of a div to the bottom with css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to align content of a div to the bottom with css

Could anyone help complete this? Or at least point to the right direction?

I want it that way

[image]

This is my code:

```css
.bbb{
text-align:center;
bottom: 20px;
}
.text-wi{
border-top:2px dashed #13aff2;
 padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
}

.haha{
 padding:5px
}
.widget-host {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.widget-host > div.host-woovn {
border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.button{
    background-color: #669900;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: initial;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-host"><div class="host-woovn">
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<div class="text-wi">
 – A<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– D<br>
– C
</div>
 <div class="bbb"> <a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">AAAAA</a></div>
</div>
<div class="host-woovn">
 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB<div class="text-wi">
– A<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– D<br>
– E<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– F</div>
<div class="bbb"><a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">BBBB</a></div>
 </div></div>
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288336/put-text-at-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it using position property. Hope this helps you.. thanks

```css
.bbb{
    text-align: center;
    /* bottom: 20px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.text-wi{
border-top:2px dashed #13aff2;
 padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
}

.haha{
 padding:5px
}
.widget-host {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.widget-host > div.host-woovn {
border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.button{
    background-color: #669900;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: initial;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-host"><div class="host-woovn">
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<div class="text-wi">
 – A<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– D<br>
– C
</div>
 <div class="bbb"> <a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">AAAAA</a></div>
</div>
<div class="host-woovn">
 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB<div class="text-wi">
– A<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– D<br>
– E<br>
– B<br>
– C<br>
– F</div>
<div class="bbb"><a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">BBBB</a></div>
 </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to achieve this if you have a child element that you want directly at the bottom of a parent is to use `position`.

```css
.parent {
   background: #ddd;
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;
   width: 300px;
}
.child {
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0%;
   left: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'm at the bottom!
  </div>
</div>
```

This method also utilizes [2D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) to horizontally center the child element. As you can see, the red box is forced to the bottom of the gray box by the lines `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0%;` in particular.

Answer (score 1):

other styles like `position: absolute` etc. didnt work for me.
using css flex-box and grid are some of the easiest way you can align items.

i did change the html a little, i.e. making content on right and left separate div
CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>

.widgethost{
background-color:green;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content:flex-start;

height:100vh;

}

.parent{
margin: 1rem;
color:white;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;


display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-between;

border:5px solid black;

}



a, a:visited, a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}


</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="widgethost">
  <div class="parent aaa">
    <div class="host-woovn">
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    </div>
    <div class="text-wi">
      – A<br>
      – B<br>
      – C<br>
      – D<br>
      – C
    </div>
    <div class="bbb">
      <a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">AAAAA</a>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="parent bbb">
    <div class="host-woovn">
      BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    </div>
    <div class="text-wi">
      – A<br>
      – B<br>
      – C<br>
      – D<br>
      – E<br>
      – B<br>
      – C<br>
      – F
    </div>
    <div class="bbb">
      <a href="/" target="_blank" class="button">BBBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```