# Positioning some text in a div HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website and I need to **positionate some text (h4) on the bottom** of a div but I'm having problems to solve it.
I had used position tags, bottom, margin-bottom ... but had no effect, so I decided to post this question searching for a solution.
This is an image of the content.

[image]

```css
#coas_content {
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 72%;
}
.row{
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.kid_card{
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.kid_card h2{
    text-align: initial;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.kid_card h4{
    text-align: initial;
    position: absolute;
}
.kid_card a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: initial;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="coas_content">
 <t t-if="kid_id">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="kid_card" style="background-image: 
    url(/prueba_coas_education_website/static/src/img/icon1.png);">
    <div class="text_container">
     <h2><b>Calificaciones</b></h2>
     <h4><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
      <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
       Ver calificaciones</a></h4>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358646/css-position-div-to-bottom-of-containing-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put text at bottom of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288336/put-text-at-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `bottom: 0` in the `.kid_card h4` css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `<h4>` is inside the `<div class="text_container">` but you give the css property `position: relative` to `<div classkid_card>` which contains `<div class="text_container">`. You need to give the css property `position: relative` to `<div class="text_container">` and set its size as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set `#coas_content` height to `100%`